# Wiremock, spring-boot, test, @AutoConfigureWireMock, .p12 File

Tags: spring-boot, wiremock

in my spring-boot project i have a lot of tests which uses Wiremock via @AutoConfigureWireMock
I changed my project to SSL and therfore have an .p12 file under resources/keystore.

As long as the file is there i get the following error at starting a test:

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.EOFException

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.base/sun.security.util.IOUtils.readExactlyNBytes(IOUtils.java:61)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:467)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:487)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2012)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.ssl.KeyStoreSource.load(KeyStoreSource.java:42)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.ssl.KeyStoreSettings.loadStore(KeyStoreSettings.java:55)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty94.SslContexts.setupKeyStore(SslContexts.java:105)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty94.SslContexts.defaultSslContextFactory(SslContexts.java:89)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty94.SslContexts.buildHttp2SslContextFactory(SslContexts.java:39)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty94.Jetty94HttpServer.createHttpsConnector(Jetty94HttpServer.java:82)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty9.JettyHttpServer.<init>(JettyHttpServer.java:98)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty94.Jetty94HttpServer.<init>(Jetty94HttpServer.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty9.JettyHttpServerFactory.buildHttpServer(JettyHttpServerFactory.java:73)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.<init>(WireMockServer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration.reRegisterServer(WireMockConfiguration.java:160)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration.reRegisterServerWithResetMappings(WireMockConfiguration.java:181)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration.init(WireMockConfiguration.java:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

How can i tell wiremock to ignore the .p12 file?

Comment: Solved it. WireMockConfiguration scans the folder resources/keystore. Renaming the folder keystore to store (or anything else) solved it.